# Angular/Javascript array find method

Tags: javascript, angular

I have started to learn angular recently. I came across a code as follows.
Consider this.members as an array of objects. There is an object which has the username bob. I am trying to get that particular object using the below code.

```
const data = this.members.find(x=>x.userName===username);
```

So there an object inside the array and I have an object stored in my const data, My doubt is that will both (the object in the array and the object in the const data ) have the same memory address. If someone could answer why changing the const data is also getting reflected in the this.members array. It would be a great help. You can also share some resources if I need to go through them to understand them better.

Comment: `If someone could answer this ` You did explain the situation but please, make sure to ask an actual question (with a `?`).

Comment: Hi Mike, I have updated the question. Sorry for the inconvenience. Hope this time it's clear. I have found the answer, Thanks for your timely response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shortly answer your question, yes. The `data` object will have a reference to the object inside `this.members`.

If you want to prevent that, there are multiple ways I'm sure, but one of them is to use `Object.assign`.

Example:

```
let data: any = {};
Object.assign(data, this.members.find(u => u.username === 'bob'));
console.log(this.members); // For example: [{username: 'bob'},{username: 'randy'}]

data.username = 'alex';

console.log(this.members); // Still shows [{username: 'bob'},{username: 'randy'}]
console.log(data); // {username: 'alex'}
```

Notice here that I am using TypeScript since you mentioned you're working with Angular.
When using `Object.assign`, a *copy* of the **enumerable properties** will be made and assigned to your variable without referencing the source.

See [MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) for more details.

Another simple way is to use the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax).

```
let data: any = {};
const foundUser = this.members.find(u => u.username === 'bob');
if (foundUser) {
  data = {...foundUser};
}
```

This will create a new object with the properties from the `foundUser`.

Comment: Thank you so much, Maher. That was so wonderfully answered. You also gave some additional information that was so good of you. Keep up the good work

Answer (score 2):

You can easily try it out.

```js
const members = [
  { username: 'bob' },
  { username: 'daniel' },
];

const data = members.find(x=>x.username==='bob');

data.username = 'bobby';

console.log(members);
```

That prints

> [   {
> "username": "bobby"   },   {
> "username": "daniel"   } ]

So yes, changing data will change the array.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Moxxi. That was so helpful

Answer (score 0):

The answer for this question is that Arrays in javascript are mutable which means they are reference type which means when I encounter the below line

```
const data = this.members.find(x=>x.userName===username);
```

const data will have the same memory location as that of bob in the array. As we all know that if we change data at a memory location every variable/object referring to that memory location will also change as they all point to the same memory location. Hence the array gets updated even though I assign a part of the array and make changes to that part alone.

Note: The above was my expected behavior. if you want the opposite behavior like if you need the const data and this.members to be independent you can use

[Copy Array](https://holycoders.com/javscript-copy-array/)

or you can refer to Maher's answer in the same page.